# Moving SQL query +JSON file generation into a service? wcf? mvc?

Tags: javascript, sql, permission-denied

I have a small front-end SPA in AngularJS that reads from a json file currently. This file is created inside of a simple C# console app.

Because IE/Edge is unable to read the local files (a security feature?) and I cannot host either the page or json file yet, I need a solution in order to 'get' the json data to my page.

**MY QUESTION: what would be a good option for this? complexity is not needed.**

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to serve the file, the simplest approach would be to just run a local file server for it (Nginx, IIS (one flavor or another)), etc.